# NVD3.js - How do I change location of tooltip on stacked bar chart?

Tags: jquery, nvd3.js

I have two types of charts generated using NVD3.js.  The first type of chart properly displays the tooltip to the right of my mouse cursor when I hover over the graph.

Right below the line chart I have a stacked bar chart whose code is displayed below.  For all places where I hover on the bars I see a tooltip placed far to the left of my cursor which is inconsistent with the tooltip on the line graph.

How can I change this default location of the tooltip to be in close proximity to the cursor?

**Here is what I have tried**

Modified css rule which inadvertently alters tooltip on the line chart as a side effect.

```
.nvtooltip.xy-tooltip
    {
        width: 170px;
        position: absolute;
    }
```

Code used to generate Stacked Bar Graph...

```
var dataAging = [{
    "values" : [{
        "y" : 13,
        "x" : "Closed On Time"
    }, {
        "y" : 0,
        "x" : "Closed Late"
    }],
    "key" : "Closed On Time"
}, {
    "values" : [{
        "y" : 0,
        "x" : "Closed On Time"
    }, {
        "y" : 2,
        "x" : "Closed Late"
    }],
    "key" : "1 - 7 Days Late"
},
{"values" : [{
        "y" : 0,
        "x" : "Closed On Time"
    }, {
        "y" : 10,
        "x" : "Closed Late"
    }],
    "key" : "> 7 Days Late"
}]; 
  function initAgingGraphs(data) {
        nv.addGraph(function() {
            var chart = nv.models.multiBarChart().stacked(true);


            chart.yAxis.tickFormat(d3.format(',d'));
            d3.select('svg#aging')
                .datum(data)
                .transition().duration(500).call(chart);

            nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

            return chart;
        });
    }
```

[image]

[image]

[image]